# rvm install 1.9.3 Permission Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I run rvm install 1.9.3 I get a long list of permission denied:

```
macbook:~ macbook$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p385.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/aclocal.m4: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/config.guess: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/config.sub: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/depcomp: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/install-sh: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/ltmain.sh: Permission denied
rm: /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing: Permission denied
More...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
rvm install 1.9.3
```